# Getters, Setters , Object Java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. The code for my `Person` class is shown below.

I have no idea where to start to for my main method, for an object from the Person class instantiated like this:

```
newPerson = new Person( 
                   "Richard Pelletier", 
                   "1313 Park Blvd",
                   "San Diego, CA 92101",
                   "(619) 388-3113" );
```

Person:

```
public class Person 
{  
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private String cityStateZip;
        private String phone;

    public Person(){}

    public Person( String name,
                        String address,
                        String phone )                          
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setName( String name )
    {
     this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress( String address )
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setPhone( String phone )
    {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAdress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public String toString()
    {

     return ("" + this.name + "" + this.address + "" + this.phone);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea too. Try to understand your problem, then post it (note that you don't have a constructor that matches your object's initialization).

Comment: You're trying to call a constructor with 4 arguments. You have two constructors - one doesn't have any parameters, and one has 3 parameters. It sounds like you should add a `cityStateZip` parameter into your parameterized constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a compiler error. Your constructor accepts only three `String` arguments and you are trying to pass four. Try adding the following constructor (or replace the existing one):

```
public Person( String name,
               String address,
               String cityStateZip,
               String phone )                          
{
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.cityStateZip = cityStateZip;
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

Comment: thank you , i was confused why it asked (String , String , String)

Answer (score 0):

While you call constructor you have 4 parameters and you dont have such constructor in your code (you have constructor which takes 3 parameters).